# Filtering tags using Rythm template engine

Tags: java, rythm

Is it possible to filter tags in [Rythm](http://rythmengine.org/)?

I want to allow specific tags like `if` and `for` while denying all other tags (especially `@{ }`).

Comment: Corrected spelling, added code tags and link to Rythm.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment no filtering mechanism. However Rythm provides a utility called Dialect to allow template author to use a limit set of Rythm directives. For example, `SimpleRythm` does NOT allow you to use the following directives:

```
"@extends",
"@section",
"@render",
"@inherited",
"@doLayout",
"@doBody",
"@include",
"@set",
"@get",
"@init",
"@finally",
"@nosim"
```

While `BasicRythm` is more restricted and you are not allow to use anyone of the following directives:

```
"@args",
"@assign",
"@debug",
"@doLayout",
"@doBody",
"@extends",
"@section",
"@render",
"@inherited",
"@i18n",
"@import",
"@include",
"@invoke",
"@locale",
"@set",
"@get",
"@init",
"@finally",
"@expand",
"@exec",
"@macro",
"@compact",
"@nocompact",
"@def ",
"@tag ",
"@return",
"@nosim",
"@verbatim"
```

In order to use specific dialect, instead of using

```
String result = engine.render(...);
```

Use the following code:

```
ITemplate template = engine.getTemplate(SimpleRythm.INSTANCE, ...);
String result = template.render();
```

There is no way to prevent `@{...}` for the moment. Please submit a ticket on https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/issues to request a configuration to disable scripting in Rythm template